# Why is Distinct not working in this LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

In the query below, the `Distinct` call doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
using (var db = new AccountsDbContext())
{
    var uniques = db.AccountMappings
        .Select(m => new CanvasAccount { UserName = m.CanvasUser, Password = m.CanvasPassword })
        .OrderBy(m => m.UserName)
        .ToList()
        .Distinct(new CanvasAccountComparer());
    accounts.AddRange(uniques);
}
```

This query returns three `CanvasAccount` objects, but two of those have exactly the same username and password. My comparer is as follows:

```
class CanvasAccountComparer : IEqualityComparer<CanvasAccount>
{
    public bool Equals(CanvasAccount x, CanvasAccount y)
    {
        return (x.UserName.ToLower() == y.UserName.ToLower()) && (x.Password == y.Password);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CanvasAccount obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using `ToLowerInvariant` instead of `ToLower`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your comparer is broken - two objects which are equal don't necessarily return the same hash code. Equality and hash code generation have to be consistent with each other. You can fix this using something like:

```
public int GetHashCode(CanvasAccount obj)
{
    int hash = 23;
    hash = hash * 31 + obj.UserName.ToLower().GetHashCode();
    hash = hash * 31 + obj.Password.GetHashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Note:

- Using `ToLower()` isn't really a good way of performing case-insensitive comparisons. There are all kinds of oddities around culture here. Ideally, use `StringComparer` instead.
- The code above assumes that `Password` and `UserName` will both be non-null. If either can be null, you'll need to check for that.
- I hope this code doesn't mean that you're using plain-text passwords. Note that if the passwords are hashd and salted, two equal plain-text passwords are likely to have different hashed reprsentations.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I must admit, with a red face, I actually thought aloud, "if their fields are the same, the hashcode should be." I'm always aware of security and that password hashing returns a different value, but was a little hurried to see a proof of concept, for an requirement I was given about 3 hours ago.